Как через python сделать так, чтобы после /start в боте в телеграме появлялся текст, а внизу кнопка, после которой открывалось мини приложение?
Я делаю бота в телеграм. Я сделал html код для бота, пользователь может играть, нажав внизу слева на кнопку играть. Но я хочу, чтобы после /start появлялся текст с кнопкой, при нажатии на кнопку открывалось мини приложение. Как это сделать? Если знаете, можете написать примерный код? Ну или показать гайд, где для чайника обьяснят все это.
У меня есть этот код, но он не работает + открывает не мини приложение, а сайт.
Мб для этого другую библиотеку использовать?


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
